# Annual Anniversary Javascript Display

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to do seems like it should be simple, or at least simple to find an example of this code out there but I have not been able to. And please forgive me, I am not well versed on javascript, I am more of a designer (CSS, HTML) but not good at the other script languages.

What I am trying to do is have a Javascript display an anniversary for a business on their website and have it update every year automatically.  Most of my clients always have me update how many years they've been open every year.  I know it's only an annual update but to have it automatically change based on a certain date would be nice.

So example. If right now my website says "We have been in business for 44 years" how can I make it so on every May 1st it adds 1?

Comment: Please add a link to "this code". You can do it by using the edit link underneath your post.

Comment: Or you could ignore that, and simply add the relevant ([MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)) code *into your question*.

Comment: The OP states that she's looking for an example of code that would do this, not that she already has some. Anna, look into the various date methods that JavaScript offers. You'll need to do a subtraction of today's date and the company's startup date, and then format that into a year. Welcome to SO. Please do read the link that David posted.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work:

```js
var today = new Date(); //get current date
var foundingDate = new Date(1970, 4, 1); // in JavaScript months are zero-based--so this is May 1 1970
var years = today.getFullYear() - foundingDate.getFullYear();

if (today.getMonth() < foundingDate.getMonth() || (today.getMonth() === foundingDate.getMonth() && today.getDate() < foundingDate.getDate())) {
  // if current day/month is prior to anniversary day/month, subtract 1
  years--; 
}

var anniversary = document.getElementById("anniversary");
anniversary.innerHTML = "We've been in business for " + years + " years.";
```

```html
<h1 id="anniversary"></h1>
```

For more information about date functions in JavaScript see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)